# How to get sublist of objects sharing a minimal attribute value?

Tags: python

I have a list of objects from a created class. From this list I need to create a sublist of the objects, which share the same minimum value, where `value` is a property of the class.

For now, I am using this algorithm:

```py
    # find the indices of the objects with min value
    values = []
    for object in objects:
        values.append(object.value)
    values = np.array(values)
    indices_of_objects_with_min_values = np.where(values == values.min())[0]

    # create sub list with indices
    objects_with_min_value = []
    for index in indices_of_objects_with_min_values:
        objects_with_min_value.append(objects[index])
```

I think there must be a more pythonic way, than using two for-loops and converting my `value-list` to a `numpy.array()`
What can I do, to make this algorithm better, so maybe that I don't need to use any for-loops. I think there could be a way with a list comprehension, but i don't know how to do this.

Comment: so your class exposes a ```value``` attribute?

Comment: @CorentinPane yes, I set this value in the constructor and modify it with some methods of this class. I don't use any getter or setter, or protect this attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do in one-line

```py
[obj for obj in objects if obj.value == min(objects, key = lambda x: x.value).value]
```

This line retrieves all objects whose `value` is equal to the min of all values.

Better even is to save the minimum value before, and then use list comprehension:

```py
#Get minimum value
minValue = min(objects, key = lambda x: x.value).value
#Get all objects whose value is equal to the minimum value
[obj for obj in objects if obj.value == minValue]
```

This way you don't recompute the minimum value for every item.

Comment: In your second line I've got the error "can't assign to list comprehension". I am using python 3.7.4

Comment: @CorentinPane, there is a typo. You meant `if obj.value == minValue`?

Comment: I think to only retrieve the minValue I have to to do `minValue = min(objects, key = lambda x: x.value).value`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` and `enumerate`

```
class Foo:
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value

f1, f2, f3 = map(Foo, (1,1,3))
minval = min(getattr(x, 'value') for x in (f1, f2, f3))
objs =list(filter(lambda x: x[1].value==minval, enumerate((f1, f2, f3))))
```

`objs` will be a list of tuples with two elements, the first being the index, the second the instance.

Comment: I think you should compute the minimum value, not hard code it to provide a clearer answer.

Comment: you're right, I thought OP specified it instead of calculating it. Added correction